# React not working. Error says (index):13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and just trying to build a simple component to display to the page.  For some reason I am getting the error:

> (index):13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="yolo"></div>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Yolo = React.createClass({

            render: function(){
                return <h1>Waddup doc?</h1>;
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Yolo />,
            document.getElementById('yolo')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JSX if you aren't using something that transpiles it. If you use create-react-app it will handle this problem for you. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app If you want your example to work, you would have to replace the JSX with React.createElement, or use an in browser JSX transformer.

Edit: If you want to play around with a script tag, remove react and react-dom and use this `<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>`

Comment: Why isn't this mentioned anywhere in the React documentation?

Comment: It is mentioned here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/language-tooling.html. I understand how it's hard to understand as a beginner!

Comment: Also, when you download React it comes with sample react files that work and yet I haven't downloaded anything that is transpiling them?

Comment: Those examples include the babel in browser transformer:    `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this answer as correct when StackOverflow shuts off the timer in a few minutes.  Is one faster than the other: in browser vs server?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the language tooling article, in browser transforming is incredibly slow, and the in browser transform is from babel 5, which is the last release of it. Using create-react-app will handle all of this for you!

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want use `JSX` try this syntax :

```
  var Yolo = React.createClass({

            render: function render(){
                return React.createElement(
                "h1",
                null,
               "Waddup doc? "
              );
            }
        });

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Yolo), mountNode);
```

more examples of pure javascript for react js exist in [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react/) in compile tab of each example.I Hope It Can Help You.